# Symfony 3 troubles with loading namespace

Tags: php, symfony

I have a trouble with my Sf3 app. I have main bundle of my app which call StoreBunlde. I create another bundle for providing payments, so I have such tree in my SRC directory:

```
StoreBundle
    Controller
         CheckoutController.php
Payment
    PayUBundle
        Controller
            PayUController.php
```

I call PayUController in CheckoutController using

```
use Payment\PayUBundle\Controller\PayUController;
```

Next I have create an an instance of  PayUController class and everything works fine on localhost but after deploy on server I have got an exception

```
Attempted to load class "PayUController" from namespace "Payment\PayUBundle\Controller".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

What is a reason of this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know how you've deployed your app, but have you dumped autoloaders with Composer? (It's also done automatically when you're doing `composer install/update`)

Comment: composer update didn't help

Comment: Did you add the PayUBundle to **AppKernel.php** ?

Comment: Did you figure this out? Sounds like you need to install "paymentsuite/payu-bundle" on your server...

Answer (score 0):

First don't use multiple bundles, instead create different controllers in your application
Next check if you have placed all namespaces under /root/src/ directory
Check if those bundles are registered in AppKernel.php
Check if the AbcdBundle.php file have the same namespace as registered in AppKernel.php
If possible re generate your bundles with Symfony command:

```
php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Payment\PayUBundle
php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Payment\StoreBundle
```

Lastly you described your issue I think:

```
StoreBundle
    Controller
```

and

```
Payment
    PayUBundle
        Controller
```

are in different namespace